# Eclipse Maven - Autosearch when writing code

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

Today I started with Maven in Eclipse. Now I have a little Question. I saw in a video that when you write Code and use a Class of another Dependency for example and go over the "Error" there should be an Option to search for the Class / Dependency in Maven. But this option is not there in my Eclipse (in the "Mouseover" Menu). 
Here some Infos: I use Eclipse Mars and m2eclipse for it. Maven is configured right so: Index Updating etc.
But I dont have the option nonethereless.

Comment: How about putting link to that video you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The option was removed long ago.

You need to search the class through [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav).

Comment: So there is no Plugin or Function in Eclipse or the Marketplace of Eclipse that does this in eclipse

Comment: I don't know. I only know that is not part of m2e (the standard eclipse maven plugin) anymore.

Comment: Is there a Word for this Function like AutoSearch or something like that?